# How to copy string to bytearray

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, byte, arrays, string-conversion

I have a StringArray that is filled with line of text and I need to take each array of strings and convert them to byte.  How

```
Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(Chr(13))
Dim byteArray() as string = Byte.Parse(splitText(0))
```

once I can get one element of the string array to convert to Byte I will put a loop around it for each position in the string array but it says the string format is not correct for the byte.parser.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do, to be honest... or what you want the resulting bytes to be. Why are you trying to declare `byteArray` as a `string`?

Comment: How are the bytes represented in the text? The `Byte.Parse` method expects numbers in decimal format, for example `42`.

Answer (score 2):

A line break is rarely a single `CR` character, that's almost only used by the old Macintosh systems, i.e. version 9 and older. The common line breaks are `CR+LF` (Windows) and `LF` (Unix/OS X).

If you split the string on the wrong line break, you will either end up with the entire string unaffected as a single item in the array, or leave half of the line break characters in the strings. Either way you won't be able to parse the strings.

For a string with Windows type line breaks:

```
Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(ControlChars.CrLf)
```

For a string with Unix/OS X type line break:

```
Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
```

To handle both kinds of line breaks:

```
Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(New String() { ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.Lf }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

To use the line break of the current system:

```
Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(New String() { Envitonment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

---

If the string contains numbers in decimal format, for example `13{break}37{break}42`, you will now be able to parse the strings into bytes:

```
Dim byteArray() as Byte = splitText.Select(AddressOf Byte.Parse).ToArray()
```

---

All as a one-liner:

```
Dim byteArray() as Byte = TextRead.Split(ControlChars.CrLf).Select(AddressOf Byte.Parse).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to parse an entire line of text, instead of a single byte.  In order to accomplish what you are attempting to do, you'd need to loop through each character in your string and parse it into a byte.  However, instead of taking the long route, you may find use to use the built in .NET parsing methods for string to bytes. e.g.

```
Dim yourBytes as Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString)
```

You can change up the encoding method (depending on your requirements), as in this example I am using UTF8.

As a side note, you can also reverse an entire byte array to a string using `GetString`, found in the same class as `GetBytes`.

Comment: Doesn't look like VB code to me.  How many times have I got down voted for posting VB code in a C tagged question?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ' Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim splitText() As String = TextRead.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Cr}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each foo As String In splitText
        'make sure to select correct encoding
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(foo)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
Dim someBytes() as Byte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes(putyourStringhere)
```

Comment: Doesn't look like VB code to me. How many times have I got down voted for posting VB code in a C tagged question?

Comment: oops well spotted, have corrected.... well unless this site is frequented by a bunch of anal pedants, I would guess never ;)

Comment: You'd be wrong about me getting down voted, as to why, maybe you are right.